# Why is my Fedora Linux system swapping like crazy?

Tags: linux, cpu, swap, load

Every few days, at differing times my system starts swapping like crazy and the load goes extremely high such that the system is very slow to respond. Sometimes I have waited 4 hours for it to recover, other times I have just rebooted or shutdown using the Magic SysRq key (so yes the kernel still responds ok and it responds promptly). The swap space and operating system is on a pair of mirrored SSDs.

When the system is going crazy the `kswapd` is always using the most CPU and the rest of the tasks near the top vary.
Here's a sample of the `top` output when the system is going crazy. The memory used at around 4.5GB is about normal for the system.

[image: top output]

Sometimes *drop caches* fixes the problem. Other times it does not. Sometimes stopping new processes from starting works to restore the system, other time not - eg stopping `cron` (which I have scheduling several regular processes) or `nagios` (which fires off regular plugins)

Sometimes I've found that the OOM killer has killed some processes to recover some memory but this does not always fix the system either.

The load on this system has not really changed for a long time and suddenly this has started happening. I thought it might have started when I upgraded to kernel 4.16.* but I reverted to kernel 4.15.* and that did not fix it.

I did write a script to collect various pieces of information on a regular basis and from that I can clearly see the times when the system starts going crazy. I don't have that data available at the moment, I'll have to provide that the next time the system goes crazy.

Here's how the load progresses, as recorded by a script I wrote:
[load progression history](http://www.edcint.co.nz/tmp/loadprogression_1.txt)

when it says "Trying to remediate high load" it is trying to drop the caches by using `sync;echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Any ideas what I should be looking at?
I need some help trying to work out what is going on.
Thanks

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: `systemd-cgtop` (and press `m`) will show the memory usage according to cgroups which will be roughly broken down by service.  This will *include* the disk cache memory usage.  (disk cache pages are considered owned by a single specific cgroup).  You could use this to get a high-level overview, of which services are using memory.  At the same time, make sure to check `df -h -t tmpfs`.  If you have big files in tmpfs, bad things happen and they don't show up in certain common tools like `top` :).

Comment: If I interpret your "load progression history" link correctly, it looks to me like drop_caches is finding very little it can drop in this log.  Note that drop_caches does *not* drop any file which is mapped by a currently running process.  (I.e., any running executable, or mmap()ed file). I think you might expect from this that all the significant memory usage will show up as RESident in `top` PLUS any tmpfs files, PLUS other fun types of "shmem" such as `memfd`.

Comment: Sorry, the systemd-cgtop feature only started working with relatively recent versions of systemd (which enable the cgroup memory controller), I'm not sure if it will show on Fedora 27. Works on Fedora 28.  You can enable it manually with DefaultMemoryAccounting= in systemd-system.conf (and restart the system, I guess).

Comment: Please provide the contents of `/proc/meminfo` while the issue is occurring. As text, not as an image.

Comment: Sorry, about posting the top as an image. When I tried as text, it was very hard to read and it lost meaning.
I'm going to add collection of `df -h -t tmpfs` and `cat /proc/meminfo` to my script and hopefully capture it the next the problem occurs.

Comment: watch to iotop as well . High CPU load often comes from io saturation.

Comment: I've had another incident and have collected a lot more information (including iotop, iostat, meminfo output etc) which is all available at http://www.edcint.co.nz/tmp/loadincident1/
The system started getting busy at 15:00 but I think I know what that was and its not unusual. However by about 16:20 the load just climbed and climb till the system was unusable. All I can see is that I have 11GB of cache and the system will not give it up so it just starts swapping everything else out.

Comment: crosspost https://superuser.com/questions/1332834/why-is-my-fedora-linux-system-swapping-like-crazy

Answer (score 2):

The system is obviously RAM starved at several points in time, the OOM killer events and the swap use should tell you that.

Nevertheless, at 16GB RAM and running MythTV+MySQL+Nagios+Apache, pserver, CVS and God knows what else (am only guessing things from your `top` output) in the same server might be too much for it. Both in RAM and I/O.

We also do not know how many events you have in that Nagios, and how is their scheduling. Too much events in a too short time, and they will start being launched before they go full round, and will eat any machine no matter how powerful it is. And probably they won´t have time to go full round when the machine starts to get starved, and suddenly you have a boatload of Nagios checks going on. And on top of that you say you have cronjobs...

I would think of having more resources, and running a couple of machines and/or VMs with all those services. A consumer machine won´t also withstand so much I/O, at some point if you are doing some serious work, you have to go server grade.

Obviously at some point, you also have to do some Nagios and MySQL proper configuration management/DBA intervention for managing your available resources.

How to organize all of this is out of scope of this answer. Just as the old adage says, do not put all your eggs in one basket.

PS. read your top image here and see how much RAM each process is roughly using (they could be using more swap, but you know they are at least using that. Do your math). That top is a very crude indicator your RAM calculations are way off bellow what the system needs.

PS2. I am mostly guessing things, and obviously do not know your specific configuration. Take the text as a general recommendation guide.

Comment: I'm not sure how valid your comments are, about what this server is running. This server has been running the same load just fine for years. Obviously something has changed just recently. I don't think it is the load it is running, but let me think some more about that.

I don't understand what you mean in your "PS".

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where your numbers are coming from. For example, you mention 2G for Myth. However, the top I pasted shows that Myth has about 8k left as resident and a 5G virtual mem size. Even now as I write this I see about 100M resident and 5G virtual size. Another example I don't understand is you mention +4G of swap. Where does that number come from? The top shows I have 10G of swap space

Comment: Indeed I made a mistake. You need to do a `ps` ordered by RAM usage. Those memory shown on top seems strangely low...

Comment: The per process resident memory shown is lower than normal, I'm guessing it is swapped out. The per process virtual size is about normal. The overall used, free, buff/cache etc is what I see when it is normal.